# How to configure graphql subscription in apollo server with nextjs

Tags: next.js, apollo-server, typegraphql

Below is the code to configure the apollo server in the Next js application.

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { ApolloServer, PubSub } from "apollo-server-micro";
import { buildSchemaSync } from "type-graphql";
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { Context } from "components/graphql/context";
import SubscriptionResolver from "components/graphql/learn/resolvers";

const schema = buildSchemaSync({
  resolvers: [SubscriptionResolver],
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  debug: true,
});

const handler = server.createHandler({ path: "/api/graphql" });
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
export default handler;
```

But in the graphql playgroup I get the following error.

```
{
  "error": "Could not connect to websocket endpoint ws://localhost:3000/graphql. Please check if the endpoint url is correct."
}
```

How can I configure Apollo server with graphql subscription?

Comment: Isn't the endpoint located at `localhost:3000/api/graphql`?

Comment: It is complaining about 'ws://localhost:3000/graphql'. I am not sure how to create websocket endpoint.